# Evitar ver una pagina sin pasar por index.php

Tags: php, mysql, session

Tengo un `index.php` que es un formulario de **login** y que al ser correcto el usuario y la password direcciona a otra pagina. El problema es que si entro a la otra pagina puedo verla sin haber pasado por el login y deseo que para ver esta pagina se requiera si o si pasar por `index.php` ¿ alguna idea para implementar esto?

**Les dejo el index.php**

```
<?php
    require('conexion.php');

    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){
        header("Location: welcome.php");
    }

    if(!empty($_POST))
    {
        $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['usuario']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['password']);
        $error = '';

        $sha1_pass = sha1($password);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_login WHERE email = '$usuario' AND password = '$sha1_pass'";
        $result=$mysqli->query($sql);
        $rows = $result->num_rows;

        if($rows > 0) {
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
            $_SESSION['password'] = $row['password'];

            header("location: descargar_excel.html");
            } else {

            $error = "Inicio de cuenta ha fallado. Verifique su nombre de usuario y clave.";
        }
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Iniciar sesión</title>
               <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css2.css">
    </head>

    <body style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
                          <center>
                          <img src="ic_launcher.png">



        <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" > 

                        <div id="h1">Iniciar sesión</div>
                         <section>
            <div><input class="form-element form-field" id="usuario" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario" type="text" ></div>

                          </section>

                          <section>
            <div><input class="form-element form-field" id="password" name="password"  placeholder="Contraseña" type="password"></div>

                         </section>

                          <section>
            <div><input class="form-element form-button" name="login" type="submit" value="Siguiente" id="button"></div> 
                           </section>
        </form> 

        <div style = "font-size:16px; color:#00695C;"><?php echo isset($error) ? utf8_decode($error) : '' ; ?></div>



</center>

    </body>
</html>
```

Les dejo donde direcciona si es correcto el login

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

        <title>REPORTE EXCEL</title>
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="Swnk" />

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />

           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css2.css">
    </head>

    <body  style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
              <center>
        <div>
            <header>

            </header>
                              <center>
                                      <div id="h1">Reporte encuesta en excel</div> 
             <section>           
            <div>
                    <a href="reporteexcel.php"><FONT COLOR="#004D4">Haz clic para descargar el reporte</FONT></a>
            </div>
                         </section>

                          <section>
                         <a href="logout.php"><FONT COLOR="#004D4">Salir</FONT></a>
                         </section>
        </div>


                </center>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por lo que entendí, validela con la sesion si existe no muestra el formulario y si no lo muestra.

Comment: el index.php es el login? no me quedó claro eso

Comment: el index.php es el formulario si las credenciales son correctas se va a otra pagina y si no muestra un mensaje de error de credenciales, el asunto que la otra pagina se puede ver sin logearse si lo introduces por URL

Comment: las otras validela con sesion, si no existe que lo direcione al index.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para proteger tu página *descargar_excel.html* debes comprobar si existe la sesión el que se crea cuando el usuario inicia sesión, en caso que no exista la sesión, redirigimos al *index.php* (login).

**descargar_excel.html**

```
//Arrancamos la sesión
session_start();
//Comprobamos existencia de sesión
if (!isset($_SESSION['email']) && !isset($_SESSION['password'])) {
   header('loacation:index.php');
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
//Etc.
```

Comment: Agrego tu sugerencia pero no funciona ... lo he puesto arriba del HTML que contiene la otra pagina

Comment: @FelixBeeb ay que añadir `session_start();` para arrancar la sesión, se me olvido en mi ejemplo, te actualizo la respuesta.

Comment: ah funcionado, gracias !

Comment: ¡Me alegro amigo, Un saludo!

Comment: @D.Bulten si mi pagina a la que pueden entrar por url y la cual no quiero que entren sin antes iniciar sesion es .html como le puedo hacer ?? ese codigo en donde lo tengo que poner ?

Comment: @fokus debes guardar dichas páginas a proteger con extensión `.php`, y el `session_start();` junto a la comprobación `if (!isset($_SESSION['email']) && !isset($_SESSION['password'])) {` al inicio del documento, como lo puedes ver en mi respuesta.